# UPS present check from command line

Tags: ups

System Preferences in Sierra seems to know when a UPS is present. How do I check this from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "UPS Installed"`.

This will return something along the lines of `UPS Installed: No`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Power Manager's `pmctl` tool to check for a connected UPS, see [Scripting Batteries and UPS on Mac OS X](https://dssw.co.uk/blog/2013-06-23-scripting-batteries-and-ups-on-mac-os-x/).

`pmctl` can output in a range of formats to make scripted parsing easier, use the `-f` flag for this:

- JSON
- perl
- XML

[image: Power Manager scripting UPS]

Alternatively, you could search the output of `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` to find the matching UPS.

I wrote Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the output of `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` provides a line status `UPS Installed : Yes | No` which seems to be flipping with me (un)plugging the USB cable from the UPS.

Comment: Is this supposed to be part of your question? Perhaps you should edit the question to add this as extra detail and delete this as an answer.

Comment: No. It's the answer to my question, which I found minutes after posting the question :)